# Can't figure out why error is triggered at register

Tags: javascript

I have this webapp, i myself haven't programmed. This function, which is used for submitting your registration, is triggering the error at the bottom. I am struggling to find out why. I am a big JS noob.
Thanks

```
function registerFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);

        if (!UserForm.validateForm(form)) return;

        var postData = form.serializeArray();
        //console.log(postData);
        postData.push({
            name: 'action',
            value: AJAX_SIGNUP_ACTION
        });
        //  console.log(postData);


        form.find('[type=submit]').addClass('loading');
        $.post(
            LR.AJAX_PATH,
            postData,
            function (response) {
                if (!response.status) {
                    form.find('[type=submit]').removeClass('loading');
                    alert('There was a technical error. Please try again and if it persist, please let us know about it.\n\nThe error was: ' + response);
                    return;
                }
                if (response.status == 'error') {
                    form.find('[type=submit]').removeClass('loading');
                    alert('There was an error. Please try again and if it persist, please let us know about it.\n\nThe error was: ' + response.error);
                    return;
                }
                if (response.status == 'validation_failed') {
                    form.find('[type=submit]').removeClass('loading');
                    var alertText = response.validation_messages.join('\n\n');
                    alert(alertText);
                    return;
                }
                if (response.nextStep) {
                    document.location = JOIN_PAGE_URL + '?step=' + response.nextStep;
                } else if ($('input.next-url').length) {
                    document.location = $('input.next-url').val();
                }


            },
            'json'
        ).fail(function (response) {
            form.find('[type=submit]').removeClass('loading');
            alert('There was a technical error. Please try again and if it persist, please let us know about it.\n\nThe error was: ' + response);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you log the response of the fail function and then provide it as a screenshot or in a separate code snippet? It's impossible to tell what the issue is without the error message. It is most likely caused by the post request failing in some way.

Comment: `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<p>There has been a critical error on this website.</p><p><a href=\"https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/\">Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.</a></p>","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}`

Comment: You should still include it in your answer. But an HTTP Status 500 means that there was an internal server error on the request you made. So WordPress most likely isn't able to process your request. So you should either look into making sure your post request is correct (the right endpoint, correct body, required headers are present, etc.) or maybe look into the WordPress error. Is it logging the error anywhere or providing further detail explaining the issue?